# Scroll-navigation to h2 in multiple sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigationbar

I'm about to develop a kind of online book.
In each chapter (section with specific id), I would like to add an autogenerated sidebar with scroll-navigation to every h2 in **that specific chapter**.
The sidebar is of course supposed to be generated in every section containing the individual h2's in that section and link to them.

I've tried this [scrollnav plugin](http://scrollnav.com/). Actually it kind of works, but the problem is that that it doesn't generate the right links because it is not ment to work on multiple sections (in section2 it actually links to section1 and so on).

Someone who got a better solution?

**Obs:** It is a kind of loong ebook (13-15 chapters, with 10-12 "subchapters" in each). So an autogenerated id to the h2 (or another solution) would be preferred :-)

The HTML:

```
<section id="1">
<h2>Sub-chapter 1</h2>
<h2>Sub-chapter 2</h2>
<h2>Sub-chapter 3</h2>
</section>

<section id="2">
<h2>Sub-chapter 1</h2>
<h2>Sub-chapter 2</h2>
<h2>Sub-chapter 3</h2>
</section>

<section id="3">
<h2>Sub-chapter 1</h2>
<h2>Sub-chapter 2</h2>
<h2>Sub-chapter 3</h2>
</section>
```

And maybe I should say: I'm still new with javascript.

Comment: Just a suggestion but why dont you start off using regular old id targeting? i.e <div id="chapterone"></div><a href="#chapterone"></a> Theres no fancy transition but the browser will scroll fine.

Comment: Because then I have to give every single h2 an ID, and it is a very long online-book with 13-15 chapters (sections!) with 10-12 subchapters in each. 
Moreover I would like the ability to highlight the current h2 on the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Document ready
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('section').each(function(){
        var html = '<ul>';
        var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        var i = 1;
        jQuery(this).children('h2').each(function(){
            jQuery(this).attr('id', id + '-' + i);
            html += '<li><a href="#' + jQuery(this).attr('id') + '">' + jQuery(this).text() + '</a></li>';
            i++;
        });
        html += '</ul>';
        jQuery(this).prepend(html);
    });
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/sh9xzc2c/**

Comment: Yeah, I could do this, but we are talking 13-15 chapters, with 10-12 "subchapters" in each. So an autogenerated id to the h2 (or another solution) would be preferred :-)
Actually just like the scrollnav plugin (i've linked to), just with the right target url's.

Comment: Thanks. Again is it possible to add a class to the current subchapter in the sidebar, based on your location on the site as you scroll down the page (NOT using the links in the sidebar)?